# python membership testing order by rarity

Tags: python

suppose I have a list X that contains a bunch of different items and I am testing if it contains any of the following: `(a, b, c)`.

If `a` occurs vastly more often than `b`, which in turn is more common than `c`, is there a way to force

```
any(True for v in X if v in (a, b, c))
```

to check for `a` first so that it can return faster?

```
if a in X or b in X or c in X:
```

runs much faster than the `any()` statement but it’s messy and not extensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
any(v in X for v in (a, b, c))
```

You've put together your `any` in a pretty weird way. This way gets the effect you want.

If you wanted to do the checks in the way your existing code does it (for example, if earlier elements of `X` were more likely to match), it'd be cleaner to do

```
any(v in (a, b, c) for v in X)
```

If instead of 3 elements in `(a, b, c)`, you have quite a lot, it'd be faster to use a set:

```
not {a, b, c}.isdisjoint(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
any(True for v in (a, b, c) if v in X)
```

That form seems more comparable to your faster example.

Comment: I’m not sure what the difference between this and `any(True for v in X if v in (a, b, c))` is—if the generator doesn’t check (a, b, c) in order when iterating in one direction why does it now?

Comment: user2357112's is the best answer you are likely to get, you should accept it.

Comment: On average `a` occurs well before the others in `X` since "`a` occurs vastly more often than ...".  That means it is faster to check only for  `a in X` first.  Your version checks each element of `X` for membership in `(a, b, c)`.  Each element that does not match `a`, must then be checked for the far less likely `b` and then `c` before going on the next element of `X`